# Сохранение преобразованного в json объекта для использования в другом классе

Tags: java, rest-assured

В одном классе я в методе заполняю объект данными и преобразую в json. А в другом использую его как входной параметр. Как сделать так, чтобы в другой класс он передавался как преобразованный?

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ResponseBody;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

class GetProdTest
{
    Config config = new Config ();

    OrdersJson ordersJson = new OrdersJson ();
    SendJson sendJson = new SendJson ();

    @Test
    void getProdTest ()
    {
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given ().relaxedHTTPSValidation ();
        Response response = request.get (config.getToken);
        JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath ();
        String token = jsonPath.get ("access_token");
        request.header ("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.body (ordersJson.orderObj);
        request.header ("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        response = request.post (config.getProd);
        sendJson.Application.id = jsonPath.get ("id");
        sendJson.product.addAll ((jsonPath.get ("products.product.id")));
        for (int l = 0; l < sendJson.product.size (); l++) 
        {
            sendJson.product.get (l);
            sendJson.Application.products.add (new SendJson.Product (sendJson.product.get (l)));
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson ();
        sendJson.appObj = gson.toJson (sendJson.Application);
    }
}

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

class SendAppTest
{
    Config config = new Config ();

    SendJson sendJson = new SendJson ();

    @Test
    void sendAppTest () 
    {
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given ().relaxedHTTPSValidation ();
        Response response = request.get (config.getToken);
        JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath ();
        String token = jsonPath.get ("access_token");
        request.header ("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.body (sendJson.appObj);
        request.header ("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        response = request.post (config.sendApp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Преобразованный к чему?

Comment: Как преобразованный в json sendJson.appObj = gson.toJson (sendJson.Application);. А не как пустая строка.

Comment: Код в коментариях не имеет смысла.

Comment: Он имеет смысл как объект преобразованный в json.